# nestjs graphql set context after logging in interceptor

Tags: graphql, nestjs, interceptor, resolver

I would like the `@Context` to host some auth information such as tokens, users.

I have created a `TGqlContext` type that is passed when initializing graphql

```
export type TGqlContext = {
  req: Request;
  res: Response;
  accessToken: string;
  refreshToken: string;
  user?: UserDTO | undefined;
};

GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      include: [ProductsModule, AuthModule, TransactionsModule],
      buildSchemaOptions: {
        dateScalarMode: "timestamp",
      },
      autoSchemaFile: true,
      context: (ctx: TGqlContext) => ctx,
    }),
```

After successful login, I want to set the context with auth data. I'm trying to use an interceptor, because it has access to the resolver response.

Although the result of the login resolver is well intercepted, and not undefined, when using the `@Context` in some queries, context data are still undefined.

How I can set these context value after login?

The login mutation, with interceptor:

```
@UseInterceptors(LoggingInterceptor)
  @Mutation(() => AuthDTO)
  async login(@Args("credentials") credentials: AuthLoginInputType): Promise<AuthDTO> {
    const log = await this.authService.login(credentials);

    if (log.isValid) {
      this.authService.accessToken = log.accessToken;
      this.authService.refreshToken = log.refreshToken;
      this.authService.user = log.user;

      return {
        accessToken: log.accessToken,
        refreshToken: log.refreshToken,
        user: log.user,
      };
    } else {
      this.authService.accessToken = "";
      this.authService.refreshToken = "";
      this.authService.user = undefined;

      throw new HttpException(`${log.error} - ${log.message}`, log.httpStatus);
    }
  }
```

The interceptor:

```
export class LoggingInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(LoggingInterceptor.name);

  constructor() {
    this.logger.log("inter");
  }

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> | Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext<TGqlContext>();
    const resu = next.handle().pipe(
      map((res: TGqlContext) => {
        this.logger.log(res.accessToken); //<--- here the data are NOT undefined
        ctx.accessToken = res.accessToken;
        ctx.refreshToken = res.accessToken;
        ctx.user = res.user;
        return res;
      }),
      catchError((err: any) => {
        throw new HttpException(err.message, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
      })
    );

    return resu;
  }
}
```

Example of a query that try to get these context data

```
@Query(() => AuthDTO)
  async me(@Context() ctx: TGqlContext): Promise<AuthDTO> {
    this.logger.log(ctx.accessToken); // <--- here data is undefined...
    const mee: AuthDTO = {
      accessToken: this.authService.accessToken,
      refreshToken: this.authService.refreshToken,
      user: this.authService.user,
    };

    return mee;
  }
```

Comment: How do you know if your interceptor is running before or after the context is provided to the GraphQL server? Why not just create a context function directly? Also note `ctx.refreshToken = res.accessToken;` which seems to be an error.

Comment: Now I see that you're intercepting the resolver but not the context function to the GraphQL server so you'll be too late.

Comment: @MichelFloyd  sorry I don't get your point. The res variable in the Interceptor is set correctly with tokens and user, as displayed in the logger. so why it is "too late"?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution by adding the auth Data in the request's session, instead of adding these data at the root of the graphql context. Not the most valuable solution in my opinion

```
GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      include: [ProductsModule, AuthModule, TransactionsModule],
      buildSchemaOptions: {
        dateScalarMode: "timestamp",
      },
      autoSchemaFile: true,
      context: ({ req }: { req: Request }) => ({ req }),
    }),
```

**in the login resolver**

```
@Mutation(() => AuthDTO)
  async login(@Context() ctx: TGqlContext, @Args("credentials") credentials: AuthLoginInputType): Promise<AuthDTO> {
    const log = await this.authService.login(credentials);

    if (log.isValid) {
      this.authService.accessToken = log.accessToken;
      this.authService.refreshToken = log.refreshToken;
      this.authService.user = log.user;

      ctx.req.session.accessToken = log.accessToken;
      ctx.req.session.refreshToken = log.refreshToken;
      ctx.req.session.user = log.user;

      return {
        accessToken: log.accessToken,
        refreshToken: log.refreshToken,
        user: log.user,
      };
    } else {
      throw new HttpException(`${log.error} - ${log.message}`, log.httpStatus);
    }
  }
```